# React Context not running in CodeSandBox

Tags: reactjs, codesandbox

I'm trying to run [this React Context example](https://codesandbox.io/s/j4z34k9om9) in codesandbox, but getting this error:

```
Invariant Violation

Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

Check the render method of `MyProvider`.
```

I have React set to 16.3 and the code itself was pulled directly from [this Wes Bos example.](https://github.com/wesbos/React-Context/blob/master/src/App.js) I've looked over the code a handful of times but I'm not seeing any problems. Could it be a context setting with codesandbox I'm not understanding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll also have to use a 16.3 version of `react-dom`. In your sandbox `react` is 16.3.0 and `react-dom` is 16.2.0. Here's a sandbox with a working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/1r1j221nl3